# How do I redirect the output of SpeechSynthesizer to a Process of ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, stream

I am trying to have a [SpeechSynthesizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.8) generate some audio data, pipe it into a [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1) of FFmpeg, and have FFmpeg save the data to a file (output.wav). Eventually, the audio data will be used for something else, which is why I am using FFmpeg.

```
using (MemoryStream voiceStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (Process ffmpeg = new Process())
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            int samplesPerSecond = 48000;
            int bitsPerSample = 8;
            int channelCount = 2;
            int averageBytesPerSecond = samplesPerSecond * (bitsPerSample / 8) * channelCount;
            int blockalign = (bitsPerSample / 8) * channelCount;
            byte[] formatSpecificData = new byte[0];

            synth.SetOutputToAudioStream(
                voiceStream,
                new System.Speech.AudioFormat.SpeechAudioFormatInfo(
                    System.Speech.AudioFormat.EncodingFormat.Pcm,
                    samplesPerSecond,
                    bitsPerSample,
                    channelCount,
                    averageBytesPerSecond,
                    blockalign,
                    formatSpecificData
                    )
                );

            synth.Speak("Hello there");

            synth.SetOutputToNull();

            ffmpeg.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",
                Arguments = $"-y -f u8 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i pipe:0 out.wav",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true
            };

            ffmpeg.Start();

            using (Stream ffmpegIn = ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream)
            {
                voiceStream.CopyTo(ffmpegIn);
                
                ffmpegIn.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
```

When running the program, FFmpeg said that the input stream contains no data, and returns an empty file.
I believe that I do not interface properly with the Process object, however, the problem might also be my incorrect specification of the audio stream, since I do not know much about audio.

Comment: Try [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap#piping)'s piping model